# "FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener" can't catch keyboard input on PopUp

Tags: apache-flex, popup, global, keypress

Suppose I have an application and a global event listener in it. Should the key events, who are fired in the PopUp, be caught by that listener? Or maybe popups are not placed in that hierarchy?
Here's simplified test-code for you to understand what I'm talking about:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()">
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
private function init():void {
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDownHandler);
        }

        private function myKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            Alert.show("It works!");
        }

        private function makeNewPopup():void {
            var win:PopupWindow = new PopupWindow(this, new TestingForm(), true, "Popup", false);
            win.showPopup();
        }
]]></mx:Script>
<mx:VBox>
        <mx:TextInput/>
        <mx:Button label="MakePopup" click="makeNewPopup()"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Ok, what we have .. after running the application, put the input focus into the TextInput and press any letter. The Alert will be fired. Now, press the MakePopup and do the same in it TextInput .. no any feedback from it.

Any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parent of all popups is `SystemManager`. So, use  `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager`or `stage`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, pity that I've missed that .. works like a charm :)

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik what's the difference between FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication and stage when addEventListener to each one?

Comment: @jason stage is top most display object in any flash application; FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is object of Application class and represents flex application. The parent of Application is SystemManager, the parent of SystemManager is Stage. All bubbling events dispathched from Application or any its children will bubble to Stage (if propagation is not stopped). So listeners on stage will always catch events. All popups are children of SystemManager, and they are "siblings" of Application, that's why you can't listen to events (dispatched from popups) on Application